# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm newbie with Python and Tensorflow and now I'm trying to learn DC GAN. I have implemented this version of discriminator:

```
def discriminator(images, reuse=False, alpha=0.2):
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):

        x1 = tf.layers.conv2d(images, 128, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
        pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=x1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
        relu1 = tf.maximum(alpha * pool1, pool1)

        x2 = tf.layers.conv2d(relu1, 256, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
        pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=x2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
        bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(pool2, training=True)
        relu2 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn2, bn2)

        x3 = tf.layers.conv2d(relu2, 512, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
        pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=x3, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
        bn3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(pool3, training=True)
        relu3 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn3, bn3)

        x4 = tf.layers.conv2d(relu2, 512, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
        pool4 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=x4, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
        bn4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(pool4, training=True)
        relu4 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn4, bn4)

        flat = tf.reshape(relu3, (-1, 4*4*256))
        logits = tf.layers.dense(flat, 1)
        out = tf.sigmoid(logits)

        return out, logits
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/oalarcon/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    669           node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors, input_tensors_as_shapes,
--> 670           status)
    671   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:

/home/oalarcon/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     88             try:
---> 89                 next(self.gen)
     90             except StopIteration:

/home/oalarcon/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    468           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 469           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    470   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,512].
```

I get this error after adding all the pooling layers.

Any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Activation/Output Size of Cov2d_3 layer (x3) is (?,1,1,512). pool3 cannot process on this 1x1 output. So, the error raises.

You should feed in larger image. Or adjust kernels of conv and pool layers accordingly.

Use this to estimate output sizes of conv and pool layers:

```
If padding == "SAME": output_spatial_shape[i] = ceil(input_spatial_shape[i] / strides[i])

If padding == "VALID": output_spatial_shape[i] = ceil((input_spatial_shape[i] - (spatial_filter_shape[i]-1) * dilation_rate[i]) / strides[i]).
```

Make sure outputs are of good enough size and final output size is the desired one.

I hope this helps !